# Move items from vec to other by indexes in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a vector `items` of items and a vector `idxs` of indexes, how can I get a vector `picked` filled by **moving** all values at once from `items` indexed in `idxs` ?

For example:

```rust
let mut items: Vec<char> = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
let mut idxs: Vec<usize> = [3, 4, 1];
let picked = pick(&mut items, &idxs);
// items should be: ['a', 'c', 'f']
// picked should be: ['d', 'e', 'b']
```

I can make it with:

```rust
let mut picked: Vec<char> = Vec::new();
let placeholder = 'z';
for idx in idxs {
   items.insert(idx, placeholder); // insert any placeholder value of type T for keeping order
   let item = items.remove(idx + 1);
   picked.push(item);
}
items = items.filter(|item| item != placeholder);
```

But I think I am overkilling it. And keeping a placeholder value for each different types is complicated, in my case I have to avoid it.

Is there a more idiomatic way to do that ?

Comment: If your indices are sorted, you can simply subtract the number of items moved so far from the current index.

Comment: If they are not sorted, you can use [`replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) to replace items with the placeholder in a single step without shifting the remaining items back and forth.

Comment: That is a very cool solution, it will solve this and `swap` will even remove the `insert` complexity. I will wait to see if there is an even more straight solution (without looping or using a placeholder) and I will close this

Comment: After some tests, in my case, I really need to do it without a placeholder, and with an unsorted indexes vector

Comment: @Loheek You can just sort the indices first.

Comment: @Aplet123 In this case the order of the resulting items will be changed. Keeping items in `idxs` order is important

Comment: Where does `idxs` come from? Is it possible you could alter that code so that instead of spitting out a list of indices, it partitions `items`? Having indices in-hand, rather than being able to tell where an item goes by its value, is limiting the available options.

Comment: No I don't think it is possible in my case. Moreover this question is more about whether Rust has this "pick many" feature somehow, like in many other languages, or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two algorithms for the problem.

The following algorithm is O(*n* + *m*). That is the best possible asymptotic run time assuming that `items` must stay in its original *order,* since that means all elements must potentially be moved to compact them after the removals.

```rust
fn pick<T>(items: &mut Vec<T>, idxs: &[usize]) -> Vec<T> {
    // Move the items into a vector of Option<T> we can remove items from
    // without reordering.
    let mut opt_items: Vec<Option<T>> = items.drain(..).map(Some).collect();
    
    // Take the items.
    let picked: Vec<T> = idxs
        .into_iter()
        .map(|&i| opt_items[i].take().expect("duplicate index"))
        .collect();
    
    // Put the unpicked items back.
    items.extend(opt_items.into_iter().filter_map(|opt| opt));

    picked
}

fn main() {
    let mut items: Vec<char> = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
    let idxs: Vec<usize> = vec![3, 4, 1];
    let picked = pick(&mut items, &idxs);
    dbg!(picked, items);
}
```

---

This algorithm is instead O(*m* log *m*) (where *m* is the length of `idxs`). The price for this is that it reorders the un-picked elements of `items`.

```rust
fn pick<T>(items: &mut Vec<T>, idxs: &[usize]) -> Vec<T> {
    // Second element is the index into `idxs`.
    let mut sorted_idxs: Vec<(usize, usize)> =
        idxs.iter().copied().enumerate().map(|(ii, i)| (i, ii)).collect();
    sorted_idxs.sort();

    // Set up random-access output storage.
    let mut output: Vec<Option<T>> = Vec::new();
    output.resize_with(idxs.len(), || None);

    // Take the items, in reverse sorted order.
    // Reverse order ensures that `swap_remove` won't move any item we want.
    for (i, ii) in sorted_idxs.into_iter().rev() {
        output[ii] = Some(items.swap_remove(i));
    }

    // Unwrap the temporary `Option`s.
    output.into_iter().map(Option::unwrap).collect()
}
```

Both of these algorithms could be optimized by using `unsafe` code to work with uninitialized/moved memory instead of using vectors of `Option`. The second algorithm would then need a check for duplicate indices to be safe.

Comment: The second algorithm is `O(m×log(m))` due to the cost of sorting `idxs`.

Answer (score 1):

If `idxs` is unsorted and order matters, and if you can't use a placeholder, then you can move the items like this:

```
let mut picked: Vec<char> = Vec::new();
let mut idxs = idxs.clone(); // Not required if you are allowed to mutate the original idx.
for i in 0 .. idxs.len() {
   picked.push (items.remove (idxs[i]));
   for j in i+1 .. idxs.len() {
      if idxs[j] > idxs[i] { idxs[j] -= 1; }
   }
}
```

Comment: This solution solves the problem, but I have +20k items, so this `o(n log(n))` algorithm make more than one second to compute, where the placeholder solution is `o(n)`. I am afraid I can't use it

Comment: @Loheek There's no `log n` here. The placeholder version is `O(mn + n)` where this solution is `O(m² + mn)`, in `m = len(idxs)` and `n = len(items)`.

Comment: Thank you for this reminder. Anyway this algorithm is not usable with tens of thousands of items, and I have far more

Comment: Actually the placeholder version (with `replace`) is `O(m+n)`. It should also be pretty cache-friendly, meaning that you probably won't find anything better performance-wise.